# After updating to latest laravel v5.2.38 from coomposer getting "Trait method guestMiddleware collision with trait methods on Auth\PasswordController"

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I am not sure why I am getting this error after my laravel was updated to v5.2.38, all were working fine before.
Following is error message I get.
Trait method guestMiddleware has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController